# How costume azure media player quality level name ?

Tags: azure, media-player

the default name like : 720p-3.5Mbps ... 540p-2.3Mbps..

I just want show like HD, SD...

I checked the documentation : http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/index.html#amp.videostream

seems there is name for video stream, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, changing the quality level menu item names to match the stream name in the manifest is currently unavailable. If you would like to see this as a feature, please feel free to add it to the UserVoice forum (http://aka.ms/ampuservoice)